# Writing file to server, php

Tags: javascript, php

I am wondering why my test.php is not working. Thinking and testing now for a few days. Finally decided to put my question here, first post ever!
I saved the code as test.php. Called it from my browser with localhost/test.php.
That's ok. It should create a file in htdocs with some text in it. That's ok too. The setInterval command does work properly because 3 seconds after start i get an alert with text *end of function* in it. When i browse to htdocs, the file is there with correct time and date, so it's written OK.
Now, when i click OK in the alertbox, the next alert as expected comes up with the text *init*, as expected. All fine so far. After 3 seconds, the first alert appears again, (*end of function*). But no file written. Click Ok and the next alert (*init*) pops up, again as expected. Ofcourse this repeats itself... So the alerts pop up as expected but only the very first time the .txt file is updated / written. Of course i ran this for a few minutes, to see the timestamp of the file change. Deleting the .txt during runtime does not result in creation of a new file. Searched for a solution but can't find it.
Why is the file created only once???

Help is appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body  onload='init();'>
 <script>
  function init() {
  setInterval(function(){
     writeFile();
     alert('init');
     }, 3000);
    }
  
  function writeFile() {
   <?php
   $f = fopen('../htdocs/textfile.txt', 'w');
   fwrite($f, 'Eriks test'); 
   fclose($f);
   ?>
   alert('end of function');
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you're trying to run a server side code on on the client side?

Comment: are you expecting your PHP code to run in your javascript function? Read about [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: You can't run PHP in JavaScript. The PHP code, including the stuff between the script tags, lives on the server, and gets run once when the user loads the page. The JavaScript gets run in the user's browser. Try looking at the source code from the browser: it will look like this: function writefile() { alert('end of function'); } }

Comment: Thanks, so far! answers within 2 mins! Yes, i have read about AJAX, of course i'll check that again. But why does it run ok only once???

Comment: It runs on the server before it serve the html file to the client, check the source code, you won't see the php code in there (only the `alert` function) - You can put the `PHP` code anywhere else in the document and you still see the file created

Comment: OK, now i get it!! Next time i'll check the source code in the browser. Thanks sofar all of you! and Alon, your answer made it 100% clear to me.